# Android, set custom timing of AlarmManager... Please advise

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hi I need to set AlarmManager to run a reminder for me to take medication.  I need to repeat it by custom amount of days and custom amount of times to take in the day.

So is there an efficient way to set the AlarmManager or CommonsWare's Implementation of the AlarmManager to remind me "twice a day starting at 9AM for the next 5 days" to remind me to take medication?  Pls advice and tnx in advance for any constructive help in sample code and in relevant tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into Mark's AlarmManager implementation, but there is no way, in general, to get the bare AlarmManager to do what you are trying to do.  You can schedule a single alarm, at a specific time, or a repeating alarm, that repeats at fixed intervals.  If you want something that handles complex schedules like the one you describe, you'll have to write or find code that does it.

Comment: are there sample codes that you know of??  I used an alarm app that does these simple "complex" scheduling like alarm me at 8AM only on business days and not weekends.  Tnx :)

Comment: In addition, if there's no sample code or resources to do these things, how do you recommend me to structure my code to accomplish what I described??

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the question:  You asked if the AlarmManage could do what you wanted.  I answered: it cannot.  The application you want is probably going to need a SQLite DB to store the schedule and the Alarm Manager to wake itself up when necessary.  It is a moderately complex app.  I don't know, off-hand, of any free example code that will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a PendingIntent with the AlarmManager. The idea is to schedule the pendingIntent with the alarmManager, have that trigger an intentService or broadcast, setup another pendingIntent with the alarmManager for the next desired event. You want to keep in mind that you'll need the BOOT_RECEIVED permission in case the user reboots their device. I have complex scheduling in Audio Control and this is exactly what I do.

Here is a pretty decent tutorial of what I mean:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Comment: u hinted at your Audio control Scheduling... can u share your code or is it super top secret??

Comment: The link I shared shows exactly how to do it. If you plan to let users customize the times/days then you will have to create some activity to let them create a schedule and save it to a database. Then pull out your info and create a pendingIntent like the tutorial shows. When the pendingIntent fires you will start a service and setup the next pendingIntent based on the users preferences

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule an alarm to the next time you want to take the medicine - according to your algorithm (for example if its twice a day, and you got to the pending intent callback for the first time today, then schedule the next alarm to start after [6,7,8,9,10...] hours).

You will need to save both last time of the alarm launch and the user settings in shared prefs/file/DB.

You need to handle process down (android killed it or the device was rebooted). In the case of device reboot you should use the boot receiver to start your service, [but you need to remember that from android 3.1 the user has to use at least one time the GUI in order for you to intercept the boot completed receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744426/broadcastreceiver-issues-in-android-3-1). The boot completed receiver should look when was the last time that the alarm launched, and according to the user settings set the next alarm launch.

In the case of android killed your service, you will need to make research, i can't help here.

[see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)